# qt read data from serial port just after open by another program

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt version 5.5.1 from windows 8.1.
When I run [qtserialport terminal example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-example.html),
program connects to port successfully, but does not receive any data.

But when I close this program and open Hercules_3-2-6 Application (rs232 terminal software), that application read data,
and after close Hercules_3-2-6 application and open terminal example again, this program works and reads data until restarting computer.

I repeat this process many times.

But terminal project does not receive any data after restarting system until port opens one time by Hercules_3-2-6 Application.

Specification of port:
Name: COM3,
Baud Rate: 9600,
Data bits: 8,
Parity: None,
Stop bits: 1,
Flow control: None

```
void MainWindow::openSerialPort()
{
    SettingsDialog::Settings p = settings->settings();
    serial->setPortName(p.name);
    serial->setBaudRate(p.baudRate);
    serial->setDataBits(p.dataBits);
    serial->setParity(p.parity);
    serial->setStopBits(p.stopBits);
    serial->setFlowControl(p.flowControl);
    if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        console->setEnabled(true);
        console->setLocalEchoEnabled(p.localEchoEnabled);
        ui->actionConnect->setEnabled(false);
        ui->actionDisconnect->setEnabled(true);
        ui->actionConfigure->setEnabled(false);
        showStatusMessage(tr("Connected to %1 : %2, %3, %4, %5, %6")
                          .arg(p.name).arg(p.stringBaudRate).arg(p.stringDataBits)
                          .arg(p.stringParity).arg(p.stringStopBits).arg(p.stringFlowControl));
    } else {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), serial->errorString());

        showStatusMessage(tr("Open error"));
    }
}



void MainWindow::readData()
{
QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
console->putData(data);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for your connection setup? That'll help to indicate where the issue is.

Comment: I use qtserialport terminal example.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-mainwindow-cpp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you must configure serial port after that you have open it. If you open the port after these instruction:

```
serial->setBaudRate(p.baudRate);
serial->setDataBits(p.dataBits);
serial->setParity(p.parity);
serial->setStopBits(p.stopBits);
serial->setFlowControl(p.flowControl);
```

they was ignored. Your second program configure right the serial port for you and the configuration remain when you start your program.
Try this:

```
void MainWindow::openSerialPort()
{
    SettingsDialog::Settings p = settings->settings();
    serial->setPortName(p.name);
    if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        serial->setBaudRate(p.baudRate);
        serial->setDataBits(p.dataBits);
        serial->setParity(p.parity);
        serial->setStopBits(p.stopBits);
        serial->setFlowControl(p.flowControl);
        console->setEnabled(true);
        console->setLocalEchoEnabled(p.localEchoEnabled);
        ui->actionConnect->setEnabled(false);
        ui->actionDisconnect->setEnabled(true);
        ui->actionConfigure->setEnabled(false);
        showStatusMessage(tr("Connected to %1 : %2, %3, %4, %5, %6")
                          .arg(p.name).arg(p.stringBaudRate).arg(p.stringDataBits)
                          .arg(p.stringParity).arg(p.stringStopBits).arg(p.stringFlowControl));
    } else {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), serial->errorString());

        showStatusMessage(tr("Open error"));
    }
}



void MainWindow::readData()
{
QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
console->putData(data);
}
```

You must pay attention when configuring a serial port, any option can return true or false; best practice want to check and manage every error that can be returned.